# Accessing object from list comprehensive search in Python

Tags: python

I am using a list comprehensive 'search' to match objects of my employee class. I then want to assign a value to them based on who matched the search.

Basically the code equivalent of asking who likes sandwiches and then giving that person a sandwich.

This bit works

```
class Employee():
  def __init__(self, name, age, favoriteFood):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age
    self.favoriteFood = favoriteFood

  def __repr__(self):
    return "Employee {0}".format(self.name)    

employee1 = Employee('John', 28, 'Pizza')
employee2 = Employee('Kate', 27, 'Sandwiches')

myList = [employee1, employee2]

a = 'Sandwiches'
b = 'Tuna Mayo Sandwich'
matchingEmployee = [x for x in myList if x.favoriteFood == a]

print matchingEmployee
```

This prints 'Employee Kate' from the class **repr**

The bit I'm stuck on is now giving Kate the Tuna Mayo Sandwich, value b.

I was hoping to do something like

```
matchingEmployee.food = b
```

But this doesn't create a new variable in that object and give it the value b.

Any help would be greatly received.

Comment: `matchingEmployee` is a **list** of matching `Employee` objects, not a single one. That's why it's called a *list comprehension*; it creates a list.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Could you advise on how to only return one result then.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to append food to each employee that matched your filter you'd need to loop through the matchingEmployee list.
For example:

```
for employee in matchingEmployee:
    employee.food = b
```

Answer (score 2):

As I've learnt that the list comprehensive produces a list (stupid as that might sound :) ) I've added a for loop to iterate over the matchingEmployee list to give the sandwich to whoever wants it.

```
if matchingEmployee:
print 'Employee(s) found'

for o in matchingEmployee:
    o.food = b
```

Thanks

Comment: Literally beat me by 15 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Since the variable matchingEmployee is a list, and in the given context, Kate is  the first in the list, you can do :

```
matchingEmployee[0].food = b
```

Comment: Thanks. That would work but assumes only 1 result which I suppose won't always be the case.

Comment: It assumes at least one result. Here a small cheat sheet on py lists: [https://developers.google.com/edu/python/lists](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/lists)

Answer (score 0):

Use the command line python to write a simplified expression:

```
[ y for y in [1,2,3,4] if y %2 ==0]
```

You will see that it results in a list output

```
[2, 4]
```

Your "matchingEmployee"  is actually a list of matching employees.  So to "give a sandwich" to the first employee found (assuming there is one):

```
matchingEmployee[0].food = b
```

To "give a sandwich" to the list of employees:

```
for employee in matchingEmployee:
    employee.food = b
```